# VB.NET Group Radio Buttons across different Panels

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, groupbox

So I have 2 panels and the same number of radio buttons added programatically in each panel. For ex.

```
RB1 -> Panel1 
RB2 -> Panel1

RBo1 -> Panel2
RBo2 -> Panel2
```

I want to group RB1 and RBo1 and RB2 and RBo2, but when I add the radio buttons to the different panels they group each other. I tried adding RB1 and RBo2 to the same GroupBox but could not achieve the goal either. Any ideas? Is it possible to manually link the radio buttons?

Comment: No. The short answer is that you probably shouldn't even be doing that in the first place, it's a terrible user experience. So - what's this for?

Comment: That's not very helpful, regardless of what it's for. I need to be able to choose between 2 options of several sets in a vertical list. They're in different panels so that the user can resize them.

Comment: They are [grouped by their hosting panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sefz7fxc.aspx). I would probably use Checkboxes with a Common event handler for the ones you want paired up to create the functionality that you need

Comment: You can arrange them any way you like, as long as you set their AutoCheck properties to False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely must have this format, you can just place each `RadioButton` within its own `Panel`; they'll be treated as separate groups, and you can then link them manually by handling the `Checked` event.

Comment: @Theveloper: Unfortunately, you'll either have to restructure or do this. There is no way to manually link the `RadioButton`s otherwise.

Comment: so how do I "unlink" all the radiobuttons in a panel

Comment: @Theveloper: Nest them in a `Panel`; that's all it takes. Just create a `New Panel` and add the `RadioButton` to the `Panel` instead of wherever you would normally put it, then put the `Panel` there instead.

Comment: I ended up going with horizontal panels with 2 Radio Boxes in each, thanks!