# Are there multiple ways to group radio buttons in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have a few radio buttons in my form that should all be connected, but I want one of them in a separate container to group it specifically with some other related inputs. Here is the general look:

[image: Radio Button Inputs]

Is there a way to group the fourth radio button with the other 3 even though it is in its own group box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fact that radio buttons are mutually exclusive only when they are within same parent. Being said that I can think of two options.

1. Let them be in same parent, handle the `Paint` event of the parent and draw yourself manually giving the impression that they are different groups.
2. You have to manually manage the mutual exclusion :(

RadioButtons are no magic, they just set the `Checked` property of other radio's to false behind the scenes.

```
private List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new List<RadioButton>();
//Populate this with radios interested, then call HookUpEvents and that should work

private void HookUpEvents()
{
    foreach(var radio in radioButtons)
    {
        radio.CheckedChanged -= PerformMutualExclusion;
        radio.CheckedChanged += PerformMutualExclusion;
    }
}

private void PerformMutualExclusion(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Radio senderRadio = (RadioButton)sender;
    if(!senderRadio.Checked)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach(var radio in radioButtons)
    {
        if(radio == sender || !radio.Checked)
        {
            continue;
        }
        radio.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems generic and easily reusable for different apps. I might consider using this in combination with Attributes of some kind as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They're in different containers, so you're not able to. I think this is a dupe of this question: [Radiobuttons as a group in different panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727415/radiobuttons-as-a-group-in-different-panels)

Answer (score 0):

This question talks about it:

[VB.NET Group Radio Buttons across different Panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493318/vb-net-group-radio-buttons-across-different-panels)

You can handle the `CheckedChanged` event of your radio buttons to accomplish what you need:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.HandleCheckedChanged);
        this.radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.HandleCheckedChanged);
        this.radioButton3.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.HandleCheckedChanged);
    }

    private bool changing = false;

    private void HandleCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!changing)
        {
            changing = true;

            if (sender == this.radioButton1)
            {
                this.radioButton2.Checked = !this.radioButton1.Checked;
                this.radioButton3.Checked = !this.radioButton1.Checked;
            }
            else if (sender == this.radioButton2)
            {
                this.radioButton1.Checked = !this.radioButton2.Checked;
                this.radioButton3.Checked = !this.radioButton2.Checked;
            }
            else if (sender == this.radioButton3)
            {
                this.radioButton1.Checked = !this.radioButton3.Checked;
                this.radioButton2.Checked = !this.radioButton3.Checked;
            }

            changing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the radio buttons can be in the same parent container. You just need the radio button in question to draw over the top of the group box.

You can put all the radio buttons in the same parent container (group box would go into the parent as well), but configure the location and the z-order of the radio button in question so it's located over the group box and draws on top of it. That will give you the behaviour you want.

To do this in the designer, to get the radio button on top of the group box (you can't drag/drop it or the designer will put it in the group box), first add the group box, then add the radio button to the parent contjust drop it in the parent container, select it, then move it into position using the arrow keys on your keyboard.

Make sure to right click on it and "bring to front" and/or send the group box to the back, so they draw in the correct order.

** a more hacky way is just to edit the designer generated code - delete the line of code that adds the radio button to the group box's control collection, add line of code to add it to the parent container's control collection instead, and handle location and z-oder with similar lines of code.