# Manipulating collection from the inside

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a collection of panels which are highlighted when user clicks on them. I want to force them to behave as a set of radio buttons so only the one that is clicked on is highlighted and others aren't.

I guess that there must be a way to manipulate whole collection (set property to false) from the inside, because the event is triggered by one item from the collection. Is there a way for the one item to manipulate whole collection? This is such a common feature in applications so I guess there must be a pattern how to do it properly. Thanks.

Comment: If you're talking about toggling checkboxes from *other* checkboxes' events, the correct approach would be for the containing control to subscribe to an event on each checkbox and manipulate the others from there.

Comment: Earlier today I've [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23065637/2530848) a similar question with `RadioButton` you can convert it to your requirements. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I did find a way to do this properly with only one delegate.

In class A I have a collection of objects B

```
List<B> b = new List<B>
```

class B, needs to have an unique ID and delegete for void metod with Id parameter

```
delegate void DeleteItemDelegate(int id);     

class B
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public DeleteItemDeleate deleteThis {set; get;}
}
```

class A has a metod like this:

```
    public void RemoveItem(int id)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < b.Count; x++)
        {
            if (b[x].id == id)
            {
                b.RemoveAt(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

when adding a new B object into List just add metod RemoveItem to B.deleteThis delegate

```
B bObject = new B();
bObject.deleteThis = RemoveItem;
b.Add(bObject);
```

Now all you need to do is add DeleteMe metod in B class

```
void DeleteMe()
{
     // and call local delegate - pointing to metod which actually can manipulate the collection
     deleteThis(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may store collection of your panels and handle required functionality as in following code snippet:

```
List<Panel> Panels;
private void Initialization()
{
    Panels = new List<Panel>();
    Panels.Add(pnl1);
    Panels.Add(pnl2);
    //add all your panels into collection

    foreach(Panel Item in this.Panels)
    {
        //add handle to panel on click event
        Item.Click += OnPanelClick;
    }
}

private void OnPanelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Panel Item in this.Panels)
    {
        //remove highlight from your panels, real property should have other name than Panel.HighlightEnabled
        Item.HighlightEnabled = false;
    }
    ((Panel)sender).HighlightEnabled = true; //add highlight to Panel which invoked Click event
    Application.DoEvents(); //ensure that graphics redraw is completed immediately
}


private void AddNewPanelIntoLocalCollection(Panel panel)
{
    //here you can add new items to collection during program lifecycle
    panel.Click += OnPanelClick;
    this.Panels.Add(panel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it

```
public class SelectOne : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    private bool isSelected = false;
    private HashSet<SelectOne> selecteOnes = null;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected == value) return;
            if (isSelected && selecteOnes != null)
            {
                foreach (SelectOne so in selecteOnes)
                {
                    if (so == this) continue;
                    so.IsSelected = false;
                }
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
    public SelectOne() { }
    public SelectOne(bool IsSelected) { isSelected = IsSelected; }
    public SelectedOne(bool IsSelected, HashSet<SelectOne> SelecteOnes)
    {   
        isSelected = IsSelected;
        selecteOnes = SelecteOnes; 
    } 
}
```